# Popular REST Service FrameWork For Java

Tags: java, rest

What are the popular REST Service FrameWorks For Java? Basically WCF equivalent for Java for REST services?

I think JAX-RS and DropWizard on top of javax are some of them. Are there more or are these the main ones?

EDIT:

Best I found is dropwizard. Although same thing as others, it is very contained http://dropwizard.codahale.com/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is JAX-RS. Its implementations include:

- Jersey (reference implementation from Oracle)
- Apache CXF
- RESTeasy
- Restlet

And perhaps some more. I only mentioned the most popular ones.

Answer (score -1):

I found Jersey both stable and useful (fulfilling most of the needs) for making few Server side applications available over the internet.
I used Jersey for making Custom Java Services deployed on Google App Engine available to Web and Android Clients. Some of these services are working with absolutely no issues since last 2+ years. I especially like this kind of stability when it comes deploying production/enterprise quality software.

What I liked most…

1. Super stable….absolutely no issues since last 2+ years.
2. Decoupling Server side from Client was super easy. This was especially important for me. On UI side, amazingly beautiful innovations are happening every 6 months….both in Web UI and Native UI (in my case Android). There is a constant need to update UI. In such a case, not having to worry about making changes on server side was a blessing.
3. Making existing Java Services available online was equally easy. I just had to created external wrappers (with Jax-RS Annotations) with limited calls to the internal classes. Deploy them to Google App Engine…….and that’s it.